# Openbravo data package empty

Tags: openbravo

(I'm following the guide [/wiki/ERP_2.50:Developers_Guide/How_To_Create_a_Table](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50:Developers_Guide/How_To_Create_a_Table).)

When creating a new record for <Tables and Columns>, there is a dropdown box for <Data Package>.

I am unable to save the record with <Openbravo Howtos Data Package> as the dropdown box has no suggested entries and is empty. What could have caused this error? How do I add <Openbravo Howtos Data Package> to the dropdown box?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Openbravo modularity concept, development can be done on modules which are in **In Development**.

Open the **Module** menu and mark the ***In Developeement*** flag for the module you're creating Table for.